# How do you get the height of a form div + error messages after hitting the submit button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

So, I've been trying to get this form to work (css and javascript), but I'm stuck on something: i have the form, and everything's basically working, excpet that i have a container for the form div: formbody, and a container for the submit, clear, etc.
The top div is set to height:auto; position:absolute; and the bottom is set to, nothing. it just had a width.

When the user clicks on the submit button, the formbody will need to resize, but i don't know how to get the new size of the form in order to set the position of the bottom div.

I just added more of the css - there's a background div that just holds the template open for the form -- I had that set to relative -- but formbody has a position absolute because the height needs to be auto in order to resize for the errors (and when i set it to auto without position:absolute, formbody shrank to 20px).

```
    .background {
    width: 0px;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:999;
    }

.formbody {
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:50px;
    width:700px;
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
}

.bottom {
    width:700px;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to position the form body absolutely? My first suggestion would be to avoid this or absolutely position the `.bottom` as well with `bottom:0px;` so it goes to the bottom and wrap them in a parent container that is relatively positioned.

Comment: can you give youre code in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work? (Here's a live preview: http://jsfiddle.net/rcMGn/1/)

Basically what I'm doing here is getting the first node  with class formwidth (as per your css) and using the DOM model to acquire its style properties.

The function getElementsByClass will return an array of all  elements in the document with class formwidth (and I'm supposing there's going to be only one) and getting the first element from the array (which is supposed to be 1) and then styling it.

You don't need to care about the function...
To get the width just the first line of the code below...

```
formWidth = getElementsByClass('formbody',null,'form')[0].offsetWidth;
```

To get the height, use this one:

```
formHeight = getElementsByClass('formbody',null,'form')[0].offsetHeight;
```

and copy the function from the files of [Dustin Diaz](http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass), the function below...

```
function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    if ( node == null )
        node = document;
    if ( tag == null )
        tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return classElements;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that when I get into the office. Banged my head on this all day yesterday :-)

Comment: Hi, i tried this, but what I actually need it to do is get the formbody height (once the user hits submit) and use the number to change the height of background (i added the code above). It's still breaking my brain. But thank you...

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle page [==> here <==](http://jsfiddle.net/rcMGn/2/) to do what you want... And edited the body of the answer; If it works, rate as right answer pls! :)

Comment: Well, I did it the easy way with jQuery...but it didn't work. at least, not on the Mac... `<script>
$( "#grow" ).click(function(){
  $( "#background" ).animate( { height: "730" })
});

$( "#shrink" ).click(function(){
  $( "#background" ).css({ height: "630" });
});
</script>`

Comment: So, I used this code to anmiate the form, but it's not working on every browser

Comment: So, I used this code to animate the form, but it's not working on every browser - Mac: FF, (No) PC: IE 7&8 (yes), Safari (no). Where can i find something that works cross-browser?

Comment: So, it looks like your code works, @edgarator...the problems is, i'm trying to apply what you had in your fiddler, but it's not taking the code in the CMS. Also, there's an additional wrinkle: I need to detect another field and error message that show up under a select in my pulldown and resize of the form again. Do i need to add an event listener for that?

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
<script>

    var formbody_width= $(".formbody").width();

    $(".submit").live("click", function) {

       $(".formbody").css("height", formbody_width + 300 + "px");     

    }

</script>
```

Comment: I can try that, though this isn't about the width - it's the height. This is jQuery, though, right? I'm using javascript in my form, not jQuery. I guess I can try to come up with a way to do it in javascript.

Comment: `var formbody_height = $(".formbody").height();

    $(".submit").live("click", function) {

       $(".formbody").css("height", formbody_height + 300 + "px");     

    }`